# Getting Warnning from tridion templating source in SDL 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013, cme

> Engine: Could not process path:
>   /webdav/500%20Website%20English/Building%20Blocks/System/Design/Page%20Designs/<%=%20linkAsString%20%>
>
> Component: Templating Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

I am getting this warning in Event Viewer. I am using C# for templating and this warning is due to get pagelink from pageid here is the code

```
            string rtnValue = string.Empty;
            TcmUri itemURI;
            rtnValue += "\t\t<%" + _crLF;
            rtnValue += "\t\tlinkAsString = \"javascript:;\";" + _crLF;
            if (TcmUri.IsValid(pageUri) && !pageUri.Equals("tcm:0-0-0"))
            {
                itemURI = m_Engine.LocalizeUri(new TcmUri(pageUri));
                rtnValue += "\t\tlink = pageLink.GetLink(" + itemURI.ItemId + ");" +  _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\tif (link != null && link.IsResolved)" + _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\t\tlinkAsString = link.Url;" + _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\tif (linkAsString != \"javascript:;\")" + _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\t{" + _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\t\tlinkAsString = linkAsString.Replace(\".aspx\", \"\").Replace(\"index\",\"\");" + _crLF;
                rtnValue += "\t\t}" + _crLF;
            }
            rtnValue += "\t\t%>" + _crLF;
            return rtnValue;
```

Here linkAsString is global string variable declared in page design and itemURI is tcmuri of the page

Comment: Hi Abdul, this question in its current form is going to be difficult to answer. Please help the community to help you by adding as much information as you can. What templating language are you using? What is the code like? What have you tried to resolve this? Where do you see this error? Etc etc

Comment: Your problem is that you have an ASP server tag as part of your string literal, so the WebDAV path is invalid. It looks like you're misusing server tags somewhere. As Rob says, though, it's impossible to be more specific without more context (and some code).

Comment: Following your edit, it's still not clear what's going on or how the code you've posted is related to the warning you're getting. Make sure you're sharing all of the relevant code. What debugging have you done so far?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have written some TBB code to replace links in your rendered output with some inline ASP.NET code, which removes the aspx file extension, and the filename (if it is index). I guess you have put your TBB before the **Default Finish Actions**, or some other TBB which is trying to parse the links again and causing some error or warning (its not clear from your question if this actually preventing publishing, or just a warning in the log).

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but changing the url of the resolved link is probably better solved in an extended `PageLink` ASP.NET control, rather than in TBB logic. An example of extending linking (albeit for a different requirement) can be found [here](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/extending-linking-for-net).

Comment: Thanks Will yes i put TBB before Default Finish Action and it is just a warning not a error.i m able to publish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think source of your problem in the next line

> rtnValue += "\t\t<%" + _crLF;

For sure this warning you will get, if webDavUrl in Templating contains "<%".

Comment: The posted code doesn't write out a webDAV URL, it writes out a .NET code block, which is why it's still not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Anyway he gets as result next WebDavUrl (if decode)
"/webdav/500 Website English/Building Blocks/System/Design/Page Designs/<%= linkAsString %>"
He gets warning because he has "<%" in the WebDavUrl...it is restricted in it.
Probably this must help author. Hope he will find, why "<%= linkAsString %>" is not replaced with valid value :)

Comment: I realise that (see the comments on the question) but it is still not possible to determine why that's the case without further information.